# Bash script - Parallel unzip and waiting for ending

Tags: bash, gzip, gunzip

I need to uncompress some archives and I'd like to speedup the process.
Here my piece of script:

```
for archive in $path; do

    STEM=$(basename "${archive}" .gz)
    gunzip -c $archive > $here/$STEM

done

for file in `ls "$here"`; do
     ... processing ...
done
```

Is there a way to uncompress multiple (all) archives at once and wait for completation?

In other words, I need something like that:

```
for archive in $path; do

    ... parallel unzip ...

done

WAIT

for file in `ls "$here"`; do
     ... processing ...
done
```

Thanks

Comment: You really don't want to be parsing the output of `ls` like that; just use a glob: `for file in "$here"/*;`.

Comment: @TobySpeight What is the difference between `for file in ls $path` and `for file in $path`?

Comment: Not much - they are both unsafe if any filenames could contain whitespace.  It's probably better to make `path` be a Bash array, and iterate it with `for archive in "${path[@]}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it quite concisely and simply with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel 'gunzip -c {} > "$here/$(basename {} .gz)"' ::: $path
```

Please use a **copy** of a few files in a small directory for testing until you get the hang of it.

If you have 10,000 files to unzip, this will not suddenly start 10,000 `unzip` jobs - instead if you have say, 8 CPU cores, it will run 8 `unzip` processes at a time till all 10,000 are done. You can change the number of jobs at a time to a fixed number, or some percentage of the available CPU's.

You can also get a progress meter with `parallel --progress ...` or `parallel --bar ...`.

You can also ask **GNU Parallel** to tell you what it would do without doing anything by using `parallel --dry-run ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put an ampersand after the gunzip:

```
for archive in $path; do

    STEM=$(basename "${archive}" .gz)
    gunzip -c $archive > $here/$STEM &

done

wait
```

Comment: If you have many more files than cores, this will likely exhaust resources; it's better to use xjobs or parallel to limit the number of instances running simultaneously.

Comment: If that is a problem, you can also just add a counter inside the loop.  When the counter hits your max, wait for the processes to finish, and reset the counter:  `(( counter++ )); if [ $counter -eq max ]; then wait; fi; counter=0`

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but its average utilisation is lower (because it will periodically block until all cores are idle) and there's more code to write (and thus more risk of error - for example, you wrote `counter=0` after `fi` when it should be before).  Why spend time re-inventing a wheel when you don't need to?